# silverlight listbox selection area

Tags: c#, silverlight, xaml

Am having a list box item template, using wrap panel in container to show as three column listbox. working well. now the issue is, i have to capture the selection change only when user clicks on the second column.

is it possible to set the selection area in listbox?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it is possible to somehow raise selection change event only when the second or third column is selected. One thing you can do is keep last selected column index in a variable and inside your selection change event judge whether the new selected item belongs to same column or not if it doesn't simply ignore the change

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Haris, I don't think it it possible. You should be able to use the mouse down event and then in code figure out the selection index from that. You could possibly use LINQ on the list box's ItemSource and find the match or use the Tag property of the item.